# Ember: object resolving of nested resources

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-pods

I've recently started using Ember.js with Ember-CLI and I'm pretty excited.
But there are some things that are not clear for me.

Here is my router:

```
this.resource("authenticated", { path: '/' }, function() {
  this.resource("contacts", function() {
    this.resource("contact", { path: ':id' });
  });

  this.resource("chats", function() {
    this.resource("chat", { path: ':id' });
  });

  this.resource("settings", function() {
    this.resource("setting", { path: ':id' });
  });
});
```

The question is - why after 2nd nesting 'resolver' starts finding objects outside of 'authenticated' resource?

For example

```
my-app/pods/chats/index/view
```

But expected
    my-app/pods/authenticated/chats/index/view

Why is 'authenticated' missed ?

Answer (score 0):

Your authenticated route is not applied in the url because you assigned it's url to the root: `{ path: '/'}`.

You should either change the path to 'authenticated' or remove it all together:

`this.resource("authenticated", function() {
    ...
});`

Now, however, authenticated is **only** rendered when a user navigates to `my-app/pods/authenticated`. If you still want to render authenticated as index, you should prefix your nested resources:

```
this.resource("authenticated", { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.resource("contacts", { path: '/authenticated/contacts' }, function() {
        ...
    });

    this.resource("chats", , { path: '/authenticated/chats' }, function() {
        ...
    });

    ...
});
```

I hope this helped you.